# How to remove or uninstall addon

Tags: add-on

In previous version there was a button **REMOVE** to uninstall or remove the addon. Im using 2.82 how can i uninstall or remove the addon. I do not want to disable the addon by uncheck. I want to remove completely. No option seen. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is it a default blender add-on ? (ie. comes with it when you download blender)

Comment: @Gorgious No its not a default addon

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes but before there was a remove button simple and directly we can remove the addon. I know i can jump to the folder of addon and delete.

Comment: @atek Is that DECALmachine addon? Version 1.8.1 is pretty old, perhaps that's why it's missing :)

Comment: Remove button only appears if the add-on does *not* come with blender (or due to a bug). BTW: You should update your OS, Win XP is not maintained anymore.